# Undefined variable, unsure why

Tags: php

```
<?php
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id='$tid' LIMIT 1";
$res1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $title = $row['topic_title'];
    $creator = $row['topic_creator'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$creator' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $row["first"].$row["last"];
}
echo $name;
?>
```

I'm a little new to PHP, but I've done things exactly like this, but this time I'm getting an error. Everything here works except for $name. I checked my SQL tables and made sure users exist and that there's first and a last area. I don't see what else could be wrong.

Notice: Undefined variable: name in *** on line **

Thank you.

Comment: If you get an error message, TELL US what it is. e.g. copy/paste it. Offhand I'd guess it's undefined indexes on your $_GET stuff, plus the gaping wide-open [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes, I know it's vulnerable to SQL injection. I'm going to edit it later to prevent that, but I'll go ahead and add the full error. Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error and what is the structure of your `users` table?

Comment: What is the error (and where does it occur)? Also, this is separate from your issue, but since `echo $name` is outside the `while` loop, it's only going to be echoed once, with the value from the last row.

Comment: `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Comment: You are not entering the while, so mysqli_fetch_array($qy) is false.

Comment: If `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$creator' LIMIT 1";` returns no rows your `$name` variable won't be set.

Comment: Your query is not yielding any results. You should test for `mysqli_result::$num_rows` http://us2.php.net/mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it partially figured out. I don't see why I got a -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code on for size:

```
<?php
$tid = $_GET['tid'];
$id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$tid = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $tid);
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id='{$tid}' LIMIT 1";
$res1 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
// Check for rows first.
if($res1 and mysqli_num_rows($res1)){
    // Use if as while is pointless on LIMIT 1
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $title = $row['topic_title'];
        $creator = $row['topic_creator'];

        $creator = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $creator);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='{$creator}' LIMIT 1";
        $user_query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        // Check for rows first.
        if($user_query and mysqli_num_rows($user_query)){
            // Use if as while is pointless on LIMIT 1
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $name = $row["first"].$row["last"]; // NO HIT!
            }
            echo $name;
        }else{
            echo 'no rows found (query 2).';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'no rows found (query 1).';
}
?>
```

Variable `$name` is undefined because the `$name = ...;` line is not reached. So make sure you `$sql` query actually returns results. It has to in order to define `$name`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get any errors with that, but what if I wanted to use $name outside of that? For example, I have a second PHP block that's inside of my main HTML. How could I use $name there?

Comment: @MichaelBlake You don't! Create functions. Feed `$name`, if exists to a function. Like `do_stuff($name);`. Easy! Or just `if(isset($name)){ /* Do stuff with $name. */ }`. I wouldn't choose the second one as, in a loop, some iterations might have a `$name` while others might not. But if you don't cleanup the `$name` between repeats, it will keep existing if created once.